# variable values aren't saved MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have tyhe following code :

```
myFiles = {fullfile(working, 'file1'),fullfile(working, '*.txt'),...
          fullfile(folder1, 'controllerX'))};

switch (test)
  case 'test1'

       myFiles = {fullfile(working, folder1, '*.txt'),...
                 fullfile(working, folder1,folder2,'test.xml')};

 case 'test2'
          myFiles = {fullfile(working, folderX, '*.txt'),...
                 fullfile(working, folder1,folder2,'test.xml')}

end
for m = 1:numel(myFiles )
    file = dir(myFiles{m});
    verify(numel(file) == 1)
end
```

the problem is that in the loop the check is performed only for case1 or 2 ie : numel(myFiles) = number of files found in case1 or case 2 so the first time I assigned values to myFiles , values aren't saved.... I wanted that myFiles = number of files at the first time and number in case 1 or case 2

Comment: your test script seems to contain errors. Especially in the for loop you use `m` as counter, but reference `ii` in the next line.  Also it would really help if the code would contain also the information for us to execute it. (eg what's `verify`,`ii` and `test`)

Comment: I've updated the code, it was a mistake...the problem doesn't come from verify function but just that the number of myFile in the loop is always number of files in case 1 or case 2 whereas I wanted the first number 3 + number in case1 orcase2

Comment: I do not understand. Can you clarify what output you actually get and what you would expect? (what does "the first number 3" mean?)

Comment: @lola Does your comment mean that you already found the solution? If so there are 2 ways to go: If this question may be usefull for others post your solution as an answer. If this question is too specific, delete the question. If you did not find the answer yet, please clarify what exactly you are asking.

Comment: in the loop I wanted that myFile includes files assigned the first time to myFilevariable and those in case1 or case2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and your comment, I think you want to merge different files (case test1, case test2) into your initial cell string array.

Since myFiles is a row array, you can concatenate them like this:

```
switch(test)
case 'test1'
    myFiles = [myFiles, {fullfile..., fullfile...}];
case 'test2'
    myFiles = [myFiles, {fullfile..., fullfile...}];
end
```

If at some later point, you cannot guarantee the size layout of your cell arrays, rather use union, in which case double entries are filtered out:

```
switch(test)
case 'test1'
    myFiles = union(myFiles, {fullfile..., fullfile...});
case 'test2'
    myFiles = union(myFiles, {fullfile..., fullfile...});
end
```